# jQuery Validate - Require a certain radio button choice if another field is less than a certain number

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a dropdown menu for a person's age, and if the age of the person is under 85, I need to require a certain value on my "current_health" radio buttons in order for them to continue. I am using the jQuery validate plugin along with a form wizard plugin that allows me to have the user navigate through the form 2 questions at a time. The user fills out these 2 questions, then clicks "Next" and validation is checked.

I have tried many remedies, and this is what I currently have:

```
var validator = $("#order-form").validate({
            errorContainer: container,
            errorLabelContainer: $("ul", container),
            wrapper: 'li',
            meta: "validate",
            rules: {
                current_health: {
                    equalTo: "#requiredUnder85",
                    required:{
                        depends: function(element){
                            return $("#age").val() < 85;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

"requiredUnder85" is a hidden field with the text that is equal to the value of the radio box that needs to be checked for validation to pass.

If age < 85, current_health needs to match "Terminal/Chronic Illness" otherwise it doesn't matter what current_health is. This is what I need to validate. Age is a select box, current_health is a radio button set.

I have been looking all over the place for help, but I have not been able to achieve what I need. Any help is appreciated

EDIT: including form markup. (Note: I am also using smarty as you can see)

```
<label for="age">What is your current age?</label><br/>        
<select id="age" name="age" {literal} class="input-required {validate:{required:true}}" title="Required"{/literal}>
    <option value=""></option>
    {include file='snippets/age.tpl'}
</select><br/><br/>

<label for="current_health">Choose the most applicable health status</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="current_health" id="ch1" value="Healthy" {if $data.current_health eq 'Healthy' OR !isset($data.current_health)}checked="checked"{/if} />  Healthy<br/>
<input type="radio" name="current_health" id="ch2" value="Terminal/Chronic Illness" {if $data.current_health eq 'Terminal/Chronic Illness'}checked="checked"{/if}/> Terminal/Chronic Illness
```

**EDIT 2:** After adding a custom rule, I can no longer advance in the form wizard if the conditions are not met, but I am showing no error message.

```
var validator = $("#order-form").validate({
    errorContainer: container,
    errorLabelContainer: $("ul", container),
    wrapper: 'li',
    meta: "validate",
    rules: {
        current_health: {
            ageAndHealth: true
        }
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("ageAndHealth", function(value, element, parameter) {
    if($('#age').val() < 85 && value != "Terminal/Chronic Illness"){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "This is the error message");
```

Comment: Does it have to be with .validate plugin?

Comment: Pretty much yes, because the form wizard is intergrated with validate plugin, and I can think of another way to do it but I would have to then manually change the form wizard plugin, and I'm avoiding that at all costs

Comment: so the value of 'validator' return true if valid, false otherwise?

Comment: @SamBattat, that's not how this plugin works.

Comment: OP, you really need to show the HTML markup of the form as well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  The _rendered_ HTML markup is far more useful than your raw page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you simply need to create a custom method/rule for this situation...

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element, parameter) {
    // your function for evaluating the element's validity
    // return true when it passes
    // return false when it fails and message will automatically display
}, "This is the error message");
```

These arguments are passed into your function:

**value**
Type: String
the current value of the validated element

**element**
Type: Element
the element to be validated

**parameter**
Type: String
parameters specified for the method, e.g. for min: 5, the parameter is 5, for range: [1, 5] it’s [1, 5]

---

Define it like any other rule...

```
rules: {
    current_health: {
        myRule: true
        // myRule: 85 // alternatively, you could pass parameters to your function
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying this, I think we are getting somewhere because it will not let me advance in the form wizard if the conditions are not met. However, I am getting no error message as I do with all other rules. I added the code to the original post

Comment: nevermind, this works fine, there was another issue causing the error message not to show. Thanks!